# What does externalized checkpoints mean

Tags: apache-flink

There is a concept in flink checkpoint, `externalized checkpoints`. What does `externalized` mean here? Is there a correspongding concept,maybe called `internal checkpoints`?

Even I don't call `enableExternalizedCheckpoints` method, but when I specify a checkpoint path on hdfs, I think I am persisting the checkpoints externally, can I say that I am doing `externalized checkpoints`?

So, I am a little confused here.

```
    /**
     * Enables checkpoints to be persisted externally.
     *
     * <p>Externalized checkpoints write their meta data out to persistent
     * storage and are <strong>not</strong> automatically cleaned up when
     * the owning job fails or is suspended (terminating with job status
     * {@link JobStatus#FAILED} or {@link JobStatus#SUSPENDED}). In this
     * case, you have to manually clean up the checkpoint state, both
     * the meta data and actual program state.
     *
     * <p>The {@link ExternalizedCheckpointCleanup} mode defines how an
     * externalized checkpoint should be cleaned up on job cancellation. If you
     * choose to retain externalized checkpoints on cancellation you have you
     * handle checkpoint clean up manually when you cancel the job as well
     * (terminating with job status {@link JobStatus#CANCELED}).
     *
     * <p>The target directory for externalized checkpoints is configured
     * via {@link org.apache.flink.configuration.CheckpointingOptions#CHECKPOINTS_DIRECTORY}.
     *
     * @param cleanupMode Externalized checkpoint cleanup behaviour.
     */
    @PublicEvolving
    public void enableExternalizedCheckpoints(ExternalizedCheckpointCleanup cleanupMode) {
        this.externalizedCheckpointCleanup = checkNotNull(cleanupMode);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that checkpoints are stored in hdfs, doesn't exactly make them externalized straight away. The externalized checkpoints are externalized in a sense of particular job instance. The standard checkpoints are only used to recover from failure and it the job is cancelled or fails they are automatically cleaned up and they have no metadata, which means that they are not meant to be used apart by this particular job instance.

Now, external checkpoints keep metadata with the checkpoints and they are not removed automatically (you can configure this behaviour to some extent). So, You can treat externalized checkpoint like a savepoint in a sense that You can use it to start another job instance after update, failure or cancellation.